# Set window size when launching MS Word

Tags: asp-classic

I am using classic ASP to download data from my web server into a word document.  I am using the following headers in my ASP script to accomplish this...

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/msword"
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=gbResults.doc"
    Response.write("<html " & _
    "xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' " & _
    "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'" & _
    "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>")

    Response.write "<xml>" & _ 
        "<w:WordDocument>" & _
        "<w:View>Print</w:View>" & _
        "<w:Zoom>90</w:Zoom>" & _ 
        "<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>" & _
        "</w:WordDocument>" & _
        "</xml>" & _
```

The data I retrieve from my database is generated by this script following the above code and it successfully downloads the data and opens an instance of MS Word that contains the data returned...fully formatted for the user.  This is working as expected.

My question...is it possible to open the instance of word so that the window is not maximized?  We would like to keep the main browser in view because some users are thinking that they have left the application running in the browser because they can't see it when word is maximized.

Of course we do not know what browser the end user will employ so an solution that is cross browser compatible is what we're looking for.

I was unable to find a solution via xml, java or asl so far in my research.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  The server has no notion of how the client is handling the response.  (Essentially, your code doesn't know anything about MS Word.  You're just setting headers and letting the client take care of the rest.)  Unless there's a way to embed such instructions in the data itself (the Word document), then probably not.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Do you think it my be a viable alternative to force the document to open in a browser...whose window dimensions can be set....and is there a tried and proven method (Java?) to force the document to open in the current browser?

Comment: No, I don't think "forcing" anything from a browser is a good idea.  The job of an HTTP response is to simply respond with the requested data.  The client machine will figure out what to do with that data.  If one is downloading a Word document, one probably expects it to open in Word.  Forcing that to change seems like a bad user experience.  Honestly, trying to control the end user's browser *doesn't work*.  It eats up a *ton* of time and effort, complicates the codebase tremendously, and users ultimately *hate* it.  Some business person may think it's a good idea, but he's wrong.

Comment: Thanks....this is the conclusion I expected....it's ok to close this thread....